Safari Web Extension google oauth redirect_uri universal link not handling in AppDelegate func application(application:continue:restorationHandler:)
I have a Chrome extension that I converted to a Safari Web Extension using safari-web-extension-converter. In Chrome Extension I have auth flow with Firebase and Google/Facebook providers, it works fine via offscreen documents as it's described in Firebase docs. I was also able to adapt auth via Google/Facebook for Firefox via identity API. Currently I'm trying to set up auth via those providers for Safari Web Extension as well.
I'm trying to get Google's id_token and Facebook's access_token in order to use them within Firebase's signInWithCredential call. For obtaining tokens I form auth urls for Google and Facebook and send them in browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage to SafariWebExtensionHandler beginRequest func in Xcode, where I start ASWebAuthenticationSession with that urls. AFAIK I should use universal links as a redirect_uri in order to be able to register that redirect uri within authorised redirect URIs in Google/Facebook consoles (as only https links can be registered there).
I'm trying to register my universal links as it is described in Apple docs and I've added func application(application:continue:restorationHandler:) in AppDelegate, but when I try to test it the link is opened in browser and handler in AppDelegate is not called.
The question is has anybody tried to configure something similiar to what I've described or can anybody tell me where the problem might be?
I've tried to deploy simple site with Firebase hosting for using it in redirect_uri and universal links, there are 2 domains where the site runs, first one I use in redirect_uri of Google/Facebook auth url, after successful auth passing I can see id_token/access_token tokens in url parameters. This site opens with a button, when we click it triggers universal link with the use of second domain (as I understand universal links don't work on redirect and we should click them to make work), but instead of opening it in my extension it opens in a new browser window (no matter which browser is set as a default one, I tried Chrome and Safari). I added both of my domains as paths in apple-app-site-association json file and put this file in .well-known directory of my site, also I added them in Associated Domains in Xcode (tried both applinks: and applinks:?mode=developer).

Without wanting to state the obvious: are you sure the universal link is set up correctly? With the json file on the webserver?
